# High Altitude Cooking - Most efficient fuel and stove type

Tags: cooking, high-altitude, stoves

We are planning a hike that will have us above the tree line for several days.  I am interested in recommendations regarding stove and fuel types under the reduced oxygen constraints as well as weight.  The factors I believe are important include:

- efficiency
- weight
- safety

Most all of my experience is below the tree line.  Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: I use an old MSR XGK with Coleman white gas in an 11 oz. bottle. I use 4-6 oz. per day for myself at around 10,000' for lunch, dinner, a few cups of tea & melting snow. I am focused on comfort rather than efficiency. So this would be an upper bound.